# create mysql table with same fields as existing table

Tags: mysql, copy, field

I want to create a new mysql table, with the same fields as an existing table.

However, I don't want it to have the same keys, indexes, etc. - just the same fields (and field types, of course).

Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
create table new_table
select * from existing_table 
limit 0
```

### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/94cb1c/1)

Answer (score 1):

```
create myTable as
select col1, col2 ....from otherTable
where 1=2
```